# Huawei phone not recognize Image in Crop Text : Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

I'm using this plugin [link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and it works fine in different android phone except from huawei phone , it doesn't recognize the text after I crop the specific text in image through huawei. Is there any suggestion? I appreciate it

**This is what I've tried**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 103){ 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){

                CropImage.activity(image_uri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
            }
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            resultUri.getPath();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable;

            ScannedImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
            bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ScannedImage.getDrawable();

            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                sb.append("\n");
            }

            String sTextFromET = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            edt_card_number_inputted1.setText(sTextFromET);

        }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ML kit for text recognition, you can find the necessary information in the [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/text-recognition-0000001050040053).

The link contains Use Cases and Development Procedure sections for Java and Kotlin.

You can find different Recognition options in this link. I hope it helps.